# group by user that has answered all questions

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table of scores per `userID`. The value of `score` can be a number or null.
Each user has 20 entries (which defines their 20 questions) and all start off with scores of null.
As they answer each question, the null is replaced by a score.

I would like a query that gets all use ids that have answered all 20 questions, i.e no nulls for that user.

I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: is this homework ? this seems like a really basic SQL query...You should learn SQL first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, and `COUNT`

As this is probably homework I'll try [the spoiler markup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers) (mouse over to see the answer!)

> select userID from yourtable group by userID having count(score)=20

Comment: It's not actually homework, it is for my work but I don't often do sql queries and haven't seen the having clause before. Thanks so much for the help, it is much appreciated.

Comment: @Dave - TBH I probably just wanted an excuse to use the spoiler markup somewhere!

Answer (score 1):

Try something similar to:

```
select userID from ... group by userID having count(*)=20
```

Comment: but the '...' should include something like 'WHERE score IS NOT NULL'

Comment: where score is not null; Select count(null) -> 0

Comment: I believe that `having count(score)=20` would outperform count(*) where score is not null